# difference between state chart,state machine diagrams and state transition diagrams

Tags: uml, object-oriented-analysis, state-diagram

what are the differences between **state chart diagrams**, **state machine diagrams** and **state transition diagrams**?
while at several places i got to learn that state chart diagrams and state machine diagrams mean the same thing but at some places it is shown as different.i could only make out that state chart diagrams represent states the system is in at a moment of time while state machine diagrams show the objects and transitions between them throughout their lifetime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UML **state machine diagram**  also known as UML **statechart diagram**.
It shows **state transitions** in the system.

> **So in UML context, practically they all refer the same thing**.

But "state diagrams" exist before UML and has many different kinds and drawing styles.

Comment: thanks for the brief answer,i will accept it as majority of sites have a similar description that all are same, but it doesn't make sense to me in using different names for same thing(in UML).each term include state but **"machine"** and **"chart"**, there must be a little significance of these terms here.

Comment: Maybe "semantically-historically" they have. But in practice no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Weilkiens mentioned in his work "Systems Engineering with SysML/UML":

> ***The UML state machines are based on the work of David Harel who, among
>   other things, combined the theory of the general Mealy and Moore machines to create a model that lets you describe complex system behavior.***

So there were Statecharts (diagrams) and then came State Machines